# zlib - is header need for gzip'd data?

Tags: compression, gzip, zlib

This is probably a really dumb question, say I have a gzipped file and would like to inflate it chunk by chunk; an observation from the gunzip tool is, if the file header is missing, it won't decompress. Now the inflate() API supports chunk decompression, and I'm wondering how does it decompress subsequent chunks after the first one, since those pieces don't have headers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inflate()` maintains a state in the `z_stream` structure that allows it to stop and restart inflation at any point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Yeah I made an edit to clarify the question.